# Node - console.log + return values

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I'm just getting started in programming and am using VSC and installed Node and am using it to run my files. My console.logs works, but I can't get return values when I invoke functions. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code that you're having trouble with?

Answer (score -1):

Node.js is asynchronous.  99% of all functions you write are going to be "non-blocking".  If you don't quite understand what that is, I highly suggest you google up on the node.js event loop, and what it means to be "asynchronous".

Once you figure that out, start using the async/await syntax, or "promise" syntax.

Edit:
I see you posted more information.  Based on what you're doing, it actually has nothing to do with being asynchronous.

The problem is that you're just returning a string value of `hihihihihi`... and that's it.  You don't print it out anywhere.  You need to wrap your call to function `a()` inside console.log().  So like: `console.log(a());`